# FreeBSD zfs create gpt

Tags: freebsd, zfs, gpt

How can i create gpt marks on working system.

```
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zroot       ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ad4p3   ONLINE       0     0     0
        ad6p3   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I want ad4p3 to disk0 and ad6p3 to disk1

```
    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zroot       ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        disk0   ONLINE       0     0     0
        disk1   ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [`gpart`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gpart) or [`glabel`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=glabel).

As you've already created the partitions, `gpart modify -i <index> -l diskX` is probably the best way to do it.

Be aware that with ZFS on FreeBSD you'll have to refer to these as `gpt/disk0` and `gpt/disk1`, not just `disk0` and `disk1`.

I'd suggest:

- removing one half of the mirror from the zpool
- applying the label
- re-add to the mirror and wait for the mirror to resilver

Then repeat for the other half.